# Images Could not load

Tags: objective-c, image, url

I use this code for endcodeURLString.

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Before keyword is use for without using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`,
and after keyword is after using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

It adds `52` to URL 2(not working), but in URL 1 is(it's working)

URL 1. before =>
`https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41e3n4R8cUL._SL160_.jpg`

URL 1. After =>
`https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41e3n4R8cUL._SL160_.jpg`

URL 2. before =>
`https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T%2BHZfQPsL._SL160_.jpg`

URL 2. After =>
`https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T%252BHZfQPsL._SL160_.jpg`

You can see in the second url, after `%2`, it added `%252`. I have no idea why this happens or what the solution is for this.

Bellow code is use in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
[Common loadPostImg:a_cell.imgProduct :[dictImage valueForKey:@"url"]];

+(void)loadPostImg :(UIImageView *)imgView :(NSString *)strUrl{
if (strUrl)
{
    if (strUrl.length !=0)
    {
        strUrl = [Common appendURL:strUrl];

        [imgView setShowActivityIndicatorView:NO];
        imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        NSLog(@"before => %@",strUrl);
        strUrl = [Common endcodeURLString:strUrl];
        NSLog(@"After => %@",strUrl);
        [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultBanner"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
         {
             [imgView stopAnimating];
         }];

    }
    else
    {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultBanner"];
    }
}
else
{
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultBanner"];
}}

+(NSString *)endcodeURLString :(NSString *)url{
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return url;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<Your original URL without percentage escaping>]]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Hope this helps